# How to remove path details from a file using shell script

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a out file which contains file details with its location. But I need only file name as the path may vary every time for the execution of the script.

for example:
result.out contains below data-

```
This is my script location (c:/users/san/server.sh)
```

I want the result.out to contain data as below -

```
This is my script location (server.sh)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, kindly mention all the details for your files/samples for the better understanding of the question please.

Comment: Can you use `code formatting`? Maybe read [how do i format my code blocks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)? What result.out should contain? there's nothing below.

Comment: Are you asking how to change the program that produces the output (answer will depend on the language used), or how to go through an existing file and modify all strings that "look like" a path, or how to edit the file to modify only the string that occurs in parentheses on any line containing the string "This is my script location", .... or something else?

Comment: If your script currently generates the line with something like `echo "This is my script location ($path)"`, you might want to simply change `($path)` to `($(basename "$path"))`

Comment: Try just `echo "$s" | sed 's,(.*/,(,'`

Answer (score 0):

The following sed one-liner will do :

```
$ sed 's/([a-zA-Z]:[^)]*\/\(.*\)/(\1/g' file.txt
```

This works if all your full paths are within parenthesis